# Select only one image checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have done a 3 image checkbox in CSS, I want to select only one image like a radio button, so you can't select more than one. I am not quite sure how can I achieve that, so a little help would be pleased.Thanks in advance

Here are the CSS file and my form:

```css
label:before {
    content: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/unchecked_checkbox.png");
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
:checked+label:before {
    content: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/checked_checkbox.png");
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
/*pure cosmetics:*/
image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
label {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <!-- section title -->
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
   <span class="title-small text-uppercase letter-spacing-3 font-weight-600" style=" color: #da7e57;">Antipasto</span>
   <div class="separator-line-thick bg-black no-margin-bottom margin-one xs-margin-top-five"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- end section title -->
 </div>
 <section class="wow fadeIn blog-details-text" style="padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 checkboox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox1" />
    <label for="myCheckbox1" class="checkbox">
     <img src="{{URL::asset('external_assets/assets/images/sangiovese.jpg') }}">
    </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 checkboox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2" />
    <label for="myCheckbox2"  class="checkbox">
     <img src="{{URL::asset('external_assets/assets/images/vintageTORTELLINIragu.jpg') }}">
    </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 checkboox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox3" />
     <label for="myCheckbox3"  class="checkbox">
    <img src="{{URL::asset('external_assets/assets/images/bolied_meat.jpg') }}">
   </label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why are you breaking your users' expectations and using a check-box instead of a radio-input for this?

Comment: @DavidThomas what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this in your js file

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this allows only one checkbox on the entire page to be checked; you should - at the very least - select only checkboxes with the same `name` property.

Comment: @DavidThomas yes you're right, i was trying to select another image in a different section and it is not working,i didn't try doing it in different sections before. do u have any solution?

Comment: @Erjon add a class name at your inputs that you want to apply and then change `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` to `$('.your-class')` ..

Answer (score 0):

Define the input type as RadioButtons instead.  If you need to group them together to make them work as radiobuttons, but to preserve your current layout, associate them together with "name" attribute that is the same.
Example here: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm